# How do I use forEach or splice properly

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

consider the following:

```
  resultData.forEach(function(data) {
    if (data.profile === undefined) {
      resultData.splice(data, 1);
    }
  });
```

There is a instance where one of the resultData objects doesn't have a profile. So I attempt to remove it. However it doesn't actually get removed, the element that does get removed has a profile ...

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

When I `console.log(resultData)` I see the objects, specifically those that don't have profiles.

`splice` is suppose to modify the array in place no? It returns an array of elements removed. **So what am I doing wrong?**

*I want to remove any object from the array of objects where the profile is undefined* I thought was doing that ...

Comment: it is always a bad idea to change to object that is iterated on. try to save the index of the element you want to remove and do it later, or push the elements which have a profile into a new list/object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter out the results directly. This way, you wont have any inconsistencies due to lacking indices and you wont have slots filled with `undefined` in your array.

```
resultData = resultData.filter(function(data) {
    return data.profile !== undefined;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You better use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Array/map) method:

```
var resultData = resultData.map(function(data) {
    if (data.profile === undefined) {
      return;
    }
    return data;
});
```

This way you'll create new array without records that have `data.profile === undefined`.

Comment: Uhhh, I think `.filter()` would be more appropriate.